# Creating a Wordpress child theme for ThemeCo's Theme X

Tags: css, wordpress, import

I want to create a wordpress child theme for Theme X.

How do I import the CSS from the original style from Theme X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalized steps for creating child theme for any theme:

1) create a directory in your themes directory in wordpress:
    */wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/Your-child-theme*

2) create a *style.css* file in that directory.

3) open the newly created style.css file and add header information:

```
   /*
    Theme Name: Your child theme name
    Author: Author name
    Template: Your parent theme name
   */
```

4) Import the parent theme stylesheet,
    after the header add in your *style.css*:

```
@import url('../Your_parent_theme/style.css');
```

If your parent theme have only one stylesheet, then these steps are sufficient. Otherwise you can add multiple import statements.

Check wordpress codex:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: It stores it in /x/framework/css directory. just modify your import statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the official child theme for X here: https://community.theme.co/kb/how-to-setup-child-themes/

Or you could create your own as long as you then edit the child's style.css to include a line such as this since X doesn't store its CSS in the same file:
`@import url( '../x/framework/css/site/stacks/integrity-light.css');`

Source: https://community.theme.co/forums/topic/child-theme-not-working/

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no child theme packaged with the theme zip archive like most others. You have to login to [Themeco's member area](https://community.theme.co/dashboard/) to download it, which requires an Envato username and theme purchase code for registration.